# When can we consider temperature and pressure as two independent properties of a pure substance?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

I thought that pressure and temperature were always dependent properties on each other.But is there any state of a surrounding or condition when these two properties behave independently of a pure substance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in general prepare a system to have arbitrary pressure and temperature.

First, you put your system in a cylinder and add a piston of constant weight on top (thereby fixing the pressure). Then place this entire set-up in a thermostat (that is, couple it to a heat bath). If you now wait for your system to equilibrate it will have the desired pressure and temperature.

So actually this kind of preparation is pretty close to the way non-volatile liquids (or solids) behave in the atmosphere (ignoring the fact, that there is some particle exchange). The atmosphere provides a constant pressure and a constant temperature, that could, in principle, be set to any value.

What you can't do in general, however, is to choose the volume of the system prepared that way freely unless you are at a critical point (where the compressibility diverges) or there is a range of coexistence of different phases (where you can change the relative composition and therefore change the volume).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same answer at Risese.  It was not clear to me if he is asserting prepare a system to have arbitrary pressure and temperature means independent.

They are not independent as one affects the other.  Let a third property float to achieve arbitrary values is not independence (by my definition).

Temperature and pressure are both potential energy.  Solid, liquid, or gas if you increase temperature with a fixed volume then pressure will increase.

Answer (score 0):

For a system consisting of a single non-reacting phase, it takes two intensive properties to establish the thermodynamic state of a system.  We know this from the phase rule.  So specifying any two intesneive properties independently determines everything else.  For example, specifying the temperature and pressure independently determines the specific volume, specific internal energy, specific entropy, specific enthalpy, etc.  Similarly, if the specific volume and temperature are specified, that determines the pressure, specific internal energy, etc.  So it is definitely possible to specify the temperature and pressure independently (provided no other intensive property is specified also).